# Java classes and java error "cannot find symbol"

Tags: java, class, oop, inheritance

Can you explain me please. Why I get this error message?

[image]

I had typed this code:

```
public class Animal {

    private int size = 0;
    private int health = 5;
    private int attackPoint = 2;
    public int getAttackPoint() {
        return attackPoint;
    }

public class Cat extends Animal {

    public void attackTarget (Animal target) {
        target.setHealth(target.getHealth() - this.getAttackPoint());
    }
}

class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal anfis = new Cat();
        Animal barsik = new Cat();

        anfis.setHealth(5);
        barsik.setHealth(5);

        barsik.attackTarget(anfis);
    }
}
```

I thought link of class Animal can assigned value of Cat and It's OK.

Comment: `attackTarget` is a method on the class `Cat`. Your variable `barsik` is of type `Animal` which is not defined to have such a method, so Java cannot resolve it. The fact that `barsik` will reference a `Cat` object at runtime is irrelevant. Declare `barsik` as type `Cat` and it will work.

Comment: Thank you all very much! I understand it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reference is Animal for create barsik and anfis object, but you not implement the attackTarget() method in this class. If you want use the attackTarget method from Cat class you should reference the barsik object to Cat:

```
    Cat barsik = new Cat();
```

Or implement this method in Animal class:

```
public void attackTarget(Animal target) {
    // Code Here
}
```

Also, the methods setHealth and getHealth is not defined in Animal class. For this:

```
public class Animal {

    private int size = 0;
    private int health = 5;
    private int attackPoint = 2;

    public int getAttackPoint() {
        return attackPoint;
    }

    public void attackTarget(Animal target) {
        // Code Here
    }

    public void setHealth(int healt) {
        // Code Here
    }

    public int getHealth() {
      return 0;
    }
}
```

And:

```
public class Cat extends Animal{

    public void attackTarget (Animal target) {
        target.setHealth(target.getHealth() - this.getAttackPoint());
    }
}
```

And:

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal anfis = new Cat();
        Animal barsik = new Cat();

        anfis.setHealth(5);
        barsik.setHealth(5);

        barsik.attackTarget(anfis);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot wrong with your code.  You don't define all your functions, you define a class inside a class (which you can do but it is quite advanced and you probably don't want to do that).  Take a look at the following which was done in Blue J:

```
public class Animal{

private int size = 0;
private int health = 5;
private int attackPoint = 2;

public int getAttackPoint() {
return attackPoint;
}
public void setHealth(int health){
this.health=health;
}

public int getHealth(){
return this.health;
}

}



public class Cat extends Animal {

public void attackTarget (Animal target) {
   target.setHealth(target.getHealth() - this.getAttackPoint());
}
}
```

/* Notice that both anfis and barsik have access to the Animal methods but only barsik has access to the Cat methods.
*/

```
class test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Animal anfis = new Cat();
Cat barsik = new Cat();

anfis.setHealth(5);
barsik.setHealth(7);

System.out.println(barsik.getHealth());
System.out.println(anfis.getHealth());


barsik.attackTarget(barsik);

System.out.println(barsik.getHealth());

}
}
```